# Intent from notification

Tags: android, notifications, launching-application

My news application runs in the background and if there is any update in news a notification will show in the status bar.

How can I identify that my application is opened by tapping the notification or opened directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

you can add some extra data to your starting intent when you start them using Boundle Object.So when you creat PendingIntent form your notification add following.

```
Boundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("from","fromNotification");
intent.putExtras(b);
```

and after that in your starting activity check that.

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String startedForm=b.getString("form");
```

now you can decide where it came from.if `startedFrom` is `null` then it has started directly or else if it is "`fromNotification`" then it has started by notification